# Are there any R packages that support Deep RNNs?

Tags: python, deep-learning, r, rnn, library

I recently found an interesting paper on what it really means for a recurrent neural network (RNN) to be deep [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6026.pdf). Depth can be added in several different ways (state to state, input to state, etc.) and the authors give several interesting architectures. I've been looking (via Google) for packages that support creating these kinds of structures in an intuitive way that is quick/easy to implement but I have come up empty thus far. Does anyone know of a freely available package that supports the various structures detailed in the reference paper?

Answer (score 0):

In order to bring more focus to your search, I advise you to check [CRAN Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) website with the task ["Machine and Statistical Learning"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html), for instance. CRAN is the official R packages repository, therefore all these libraries are freely available and easy to use in R.

This page gives a detailed overview of many available packages with explainations about the usage. For instance, here is a package you may find useful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deepNN/index.html.

Hope this helps!